# Exporting matplotlib 3d scatter plot as html, possible?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, mpld3, scatter3d

Wish to have interactive 3D Scatter plot in browser. The plot is built using matplotlib and should be saved as html.

Closest solution found is mpld3 library, but it works only for 2d scatter plot and not 3d.

Plotly is ruled out it has restrictions on private plots.
Did not see any equivalent app for Bokeh standalone mode.

Any other suggestions that can save matplotlib plot to html and retain the interactivity?

Comment: I am also searching for the same solution. @Yogesh did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnidhyaBhatnagar No. Looks like its not provided matplotlib

Comment: Have you considered holoview instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try figure out how the interactive mode in `Jupyter` works.
The [official docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html) describe how to use *magic* for using **interactive mode** in Jupyter notebooks which can be saved in HTML.
If you want just the plot, try exporting it by constructing the component yourself via script and saving the HTML with the component only. There should be some way to do that.

Alternatively, if it is a one time thing, just save the notebook's HTML and remove all the parts that irrelevant.